# get current age when datepicker change jquery

Tags: jquery

```
$('#dob').datepicker({
    onSelect: function(value, ui) {
        var today = new Date(),
            dob = new Date(value),
            age = new Date(today - dob).getFullYear() - 1970;

        $('#age').text(age);
    },
    maxDate: '+0d',
    yearRange: '1920:2010',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true
});
```

I am using this code to get the current age when datepicker change value.

I am just confused what `1970` stands for in this `age = new Date(today - dob).getFullYear() - 1970;` do i need to change it to make it dynamic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subtraction of `1970` is required because when providing an integer value to the `Date()` constructor (as is the case for `new Date(today - dob)`) it is assumed that you are providing the number of milliseconds since the January 1st 1970 epoch.

Therefore you need to subtract `1970` from the year value of the date resulting from the DoB calculation to get the age of the user.

Your code is completely correct. You will never need to change the calculation.

Answer (score 1):

Your `datepicker` plugin uses timestamp values, which represent seconds from the Unix Epoch on January 1st, 1970 at UTC. Therefore, you have to calculate years passed, than deduct the starting year.

So, the answer is: No, you do not need to change anything, the age you get is already dynamic.